# How to remove custom auxiliary field in QGIS 3.2?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

In QGIS 3.2 I have created custom auxiliary field (manually). Then I wanted to remove it but it didn't work with this field, worked only with qgis added ones.

[image]

Is it a bug or there is another way?

Comment: That sounds like a bug. Auxiliary fields are a fairly new feature, and there are at least five currently open bugs. I didn't see this issue on the list, so you should [report it](https://issues.qgis.org).

Comment: Done, I've reported.